# Cannot import model from trransformers/simpletransformers:

Tags: python, nlp, artificial-intelligence

The instruction that causes the error is:

'from simpletransformers.conv_ai import ConvAIModel'

The error thrown mentions each time 'cached_path' from 'transformers' and points to transformers' init.py.

This is from within a virtual environment, with all dependencies installed and up to date. Python3.10, Linux.

All 6 other models except from the one above and NERModel are imported without error.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I edited conv _ai_uitls.py to comment out the import of 'cached_path' and hard-coded the source. I don't like to do that sort of things but I didn't know what else... There is also the issue of collections, which does not import Iterable either. Edited again replacing collections with collections.abc. Sloppy but at least it works. Posted my own answer to help the other 3 guys who might be interested.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).